# How to assign value to objects in java

Tags: java, arraylist, java.util.scanner

How do I add a value to my `ArrayList` in java then print out the value to each object.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class exercise {
private ArrayList<String> files;
  public void ArrayList() {
    a = new ArrayList<>();
  }

  public void addObject() {
    a.add("blue")
    a.add("green")
    a.add("yellow")
  }

  public void addValue(String Object) {
    for (String filenames : a)
      Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

    int n = reader.nextInt();
    a.set(n)
  }
}
```

I want to try assign values by user input to "blue" , "green" and "yellow" so it can be any value

Comment: Where did you get the ArrayList `a` from? Where do you declare it?

Comment: Firstly, class declarations cannot have parentheses.

Comment: private ArrayList<String> a;

Comment: First, fix compile errors and format your code properly. Second, it is totally unclear what you are trying to achieve with your code. You can use java ArrayList directly without some weird wrappers on top of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:**

You want to take user's input and if it's a predefined color, like "blue", then add a predefined number for that color, like 3, to a list? Right?

If that is the case then this code takes user's input from the console, checks if that input is a predefined color and then stores a matching number in the `ArrayList`.

When the user enters '**stop**' then the program **prints only the numbers** in the list and then terminates.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Exercise {

    private static ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // You can initialize your ArrayList here as well

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String userInput = null;
        int number = 0;

        do{
            // Read inputs as long as user did not entered 'stop'
            userInput = readUserInput();
            number = createNumberFromColor(userInput);
            // add the number to the list if it's not 0
            if (number!=0) {
                list.add(number);   
            }
        }while (!userInput.equals("stop"));

        // If you want afterwards you can print the list elements
        System.out.println("The list contains:");
        for (int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
            System.out.print(""+list.get(i)+" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    private static String readUserInput(){
        // This is an easier way to read the user input from the console
        // than using the Scanner class, which needs to be closed etc...
        return System.console().readLine();
    }

    private static int createNumberFromColor(String input){
        switch (input) {

            // Add your own cases here, for example case "red": return 1, etc...

            case "blue":
            return 5;

            case "yellow":
            return 3;

            // If the input was not a known color then return 0
            default:
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Careful the class here is named `Exercise`, not `exercice`.

Comment: Im trying to add a value to the previous items in the ArrayList such as blue = 5 or yellow = 3 instead of terminated the items in it

Comment: So if the user inserts 5 you will assign "blue", if he inserts 3 you will assign "yellow" etc?

Comment: @henchness Check the new code snippet and tell me if that's what you've wanted.